# get activeTextArea value to Jquery in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am new in Yii.
I have a view file with following code

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($model,'adremarks');?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Swap',array('id'=>'swap'));?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

I want to access the value of text area to my script, here my jQuery script

```
var adremarks=  $("textarea#adremarks").val();
        alert(adremarks);
```

But I cant get the value there, Is this the right way else how can I get a text area value to script
Thanks in advance

Comment: the id in yii form elements are generally `Model_fieldname`, so in your case it should be `Model_adremarks`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `activeTextArea` does not have html ID. You need to add id in this way:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($model,'adremarks', array("id" => "adremarks"));?>
```